# What exactly constitutes the "name" of an object for the purposes of object replacement?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to [basic.life]/8,

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or
>   released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that
>   pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original
>   object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be
>   used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied, and
> - the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> - the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static
>     data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and
> - the original object was a most derived object (4.5) of type `T` and the new object is a most derived
>     object of type `T` (that is, they are not base class subobjects).
>
> ... [ *Note:* If these conditions are not met, a pointer to the new object can be obtained from a
>   pointer that represents the address of its storage by calling `std::launder` (21.6). — end note ]

The standard contains an example that demonstrates that when there is a `const` subobject, "the name of the original object" fails to refer to the new object, and use of that name causes UB. It is located in [intro.object]/2:

> Objects can contain other objects, called *subobjects*. A subobject can be a *member subobject* (12.2), a *base
>   class subobject* (Clause 13), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is
>   called a *complete object*. If an object is created in storage associated with a member subobject or array
>   element *e* (which may or may not be within its lifetime), the created object is a subobject of *e*’s containing
>   object if:
>
> - the lifetime of *e*’s containing object has begun and not ended, and
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location associated with *e*, and
> - the new object is of the same type as *e* (ignoring cv-qualification).
>
> [ *Note:* If the subobject contains a reference member or a `const` subobject, the name of the original subobject
>   cannot be used to access the new object (6.8). — *end note* ] [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X { const int n; };
> union U { X x; float f; };
> void tong() {
>   U u = {{ 1 }};
>   u.f = 5.f;                          // OK, creates new subobject of u (12.3)
>   X *p = new (&u.x) X {2};            // OK, creates new subobject of u
>   assert(p->n == 2);                  // OK
>   assert(*std::launder(&u.x.n) == 2); // OK
>   assert(u.x.n == 2);                 // undefined behavior, u.x does not name new subobject
> }
> ```

However, it would seem to me that the fact that [basic.life]/8 doesn't give the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `u.x.n` defined behaviour is irrelevant, because it is given defined behaviour by [expr.ref]/4.2, which has the following to say about the class member access expression `E1.E2`:

> If `E2` is a non-static data member and the type of `E1` is “*cq1* *vq1* `X`”, and the type of `E2` is “*cq2* *vq2* `T`”,
>   the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the first expression. ...

My reading of this is that the expression `u.x` yields an lvalue referring to the *current* `x` subobject of whatever object `u` currently refers to. Since, according to [intro.object]/2, the creation of the new `X` object in the place of `u.x` causes the new `X` object to actually be a subobject of `u`, performing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `u.x.n` should be well-defined.

If we assume that the UB in this example reflects the intent of the standard, it appears that we must read [basic.life]/8 as saying that *notwithstanding* the fact that certain expressions may appear to access the new object (in this case, due to [expr.ref]/4.2), they are nonetheless UB if they attempt the access using the original object's "name". (Or, in practical terms, that the compiler may assume that the "name" continues to refer to the original object, and thus not re-read the `const` member's value.)

Normally, though, I would not think that `u.x` counts as "naming" the `X` subobject of `u`, because I think that subobjects do not have names. Thus, [basic.life]/8 appears to be saying that UB occurs in some particular situations but without precisely explaining what those situations are.

Thus, my questions are:

1. Am I correct in saying that [basic.life]/8 *causes* this example to contain UB rather than simply failing to give it defined behaviour?
2. Is there a precise specification of *which* cases are given UB by [basic.life]/8?
3. Should the standard be reworded to be more clear on when [basic.life]/8 causes UB (*i.e.,* when `std::launder` is needed)?

Comment: Just because it is "a subobject of `u`" does not mean that it is actually the object named `u.x`.

Answer (score 3):

> My reading of this is that the expression `u.x` yields an lvalue referring to the current `x` subobject of whatever object `u` currently refers to.

And that's true. What you misunderstand is what "the current `x` subobject" means.

When you do `new (&u.x) X {2}`, that creates a new object at the address of `u.x`. However, nowhere in the standard does it say that this object is named `x` or `u.x`. Yes, it is a subobject of `u`, but it *has no name*. Nowhere does the standard say that the newly created subobject has that name, or any name for that matter.

Indeed, if what you said was true, [basic.life]/8 and `launder` wouldn't need to exist at all, since an object in overlaid storage of another object would always be accessible through the name of the old object.

> Normally, though, I would not think that `u.x` counts as "naming" the `X` subobject of `u`, because I think that subobjects do not have names.

I don't know how you came to that conclusion, since you quoted a part of the specification that clearly states that member subobjects can have names:

> the expression designates the *named member* of the object

Emphasis added. That clearly suggests to me that the member subobject has a name, and the expression `u.x` designates the name of that particular member subobject (not merely any member subobject in that address of the appropriate type).

That is, just as `u` refers specifically to the object which was declared by the declaration of `u`, `u.x` refers specifically to the `x`-named member of the object declared by the declaration `u`.

Comment: In think that this adjective in [basic.life]/8 *the name of the **original** object*, clearly corroborate your answer.

Comment: Hm. Looks like the Standard could be interpreted as the set of member subobjects is not determined by a class definition, but could be extended in runtime.

Comment: I am trying to find a clear connection between a name and an object. The only paragraph I found is [basic]/6: *A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object.
The variable's name, if any, denotes the reference or object.* Are non static data members variables?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The set of subobojects can be extended. Nowhere does it say that these alternatively created subobjects would be members.

Comment: @NicolBolas why you call them 'subobjects', then?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Because they're *subobjects*. The term "subobject" exists to be able to distinguish between [different kinds of subobjects](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#2). Base classes are *also* subobjects, but they're definitely not *members*.

Comment: @NicolBolas and what kind of subobjects these new objects are, if not member subobjects?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Does the standard say that subobjects *must* be one of those types of subobjects? It says that they "can be", not "must be".

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think the Standard implies such a permissive interpretation. Anything which was not explicitly defined goes into the undefined behavior trash bin.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: ... I don't understand what you're saying. The standard does not say that a subobject must be one of those categories. And the standard does not say that the newly created subobject is the category of the subobject it is overlaying. Therefore... it isn't one of those categories. This is well defined. It doesn't have to explicitly say that the subobject is not one of those categories. Just like it does not explicitly have to say that integers are not class types. We know they're not class types because the standard doesn't say that they are.

Comment: If a definition of an object is not an introduction of variables denoting the non static data member so there is nothing in the standard that says that `a.b` names a subobject. `a.b` is neither *a pointer that pointed to the original object*, not *a reference that referred to the original object* , nor *the name of the original object*. So [basic.life]/8 does not apply to class member access expression.

Comment: @Oliv: If member subobjects are not named, then explain what "the expression designates the named member of the object" means. Coupled with the non-normative text within [intro.object]/2 where it does clearly state that it applies to class member access expressions, I would take that as confirmation that members of an object are named.

Comment: My interpretation is that members have names, but member subobjects do not; the "named member" in this case is what we would normally call "`U::x`", and the phrase "of the object" then implies that the expression denotes the `x` member of the object `u`, that is, `u.x`. But I think that the individual subobject `u.x` does not have a name.